# UIDatePicker UIDatePickerStyle = .compact notification when pop-up calendar is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I would like to receive a notification when the user dismisses the pop-up calendar for a .compact style UIDatePicker.
The user may trigger several valueChanged while trying to select the right date, so I would like to get notified when the user taps outside the calendar to dismiss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to observe `editingDidEnd` control event:

```
yourDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourCallback), for: .editingDidEnd)
```

Comment: editingDidEnd is the answer. Apple only cares to mention valueChanged in the UIDatePicker doc page, not editingDidEnd. However, Microsoft mentions several events (including EditingDidEnd) in its Xamarin UIDatePicker doc page...